# R what is this error in rSymPy?

Tags: r

```
install.packages("rJava")
require(rJava)
install.packages("xlsxjars")
require(xlsxjars)
install.packages("rSymPy")
require(rSymPy)
```

The above codes have been successfully run. And below I use the testing codes:

```
sympy("var('x')")## it is a code recommender by package reference
```

with error:
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'var' is not defined
How to fix this error? This error happens in R language not python, I want to know how to fix it in R.